# How can I generate an array with a list of start and end dates which loop every 27 days?

Tags: php, laravel, date, calendar, generate

Example, I'm looking to generate dates like this

```
    $data = [
        ['title'=>'Winter', 'start_date'=>'2018-09-20', 'end_date'=>'2018-09-27'],
        ['title'=>'Spring', 'start_date'=>'2018-09-27', 'end_date'=>'2018-10-04'],
        ['title'=>'Summer', 'start_date'=>'2018-10-04', 'end_date'=>'2018-10-11'],
        ['title'=>'Autumn', 'start_date'=>'2018-10-11', 'end_date'=>'2018-10-17'],
        ['title'=>'Winter', 'start_date'=>'2018-10-17', 'end_date'=>'2018-10-24'],
    ];
```

And they would loop around, the start_date of each season is 27 days apart from eachover, and each season always loops around in the correct order e.g.

Winter

Spring

Summer

Autumn

This happens every 7 days,

What I want to do is create an array which would prefill these dates 100 times, I then will call the CRON in my application every X number of days to generate more days.

I'm  just confused how I would go about generating an array with these dates, I'm not sure how to start?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use something like this:

```
$seasons = ['Winter', 'Spring', 'Summer', 'Autumn'];
$startDate = \Carbon\Carbon::parse('2018-09-20');
$data = [];

for ($i=0; $i<100; ++ $i) {
    $data[] = [
        'title' => $seasons[$i % 4],
        'start_date' => $startDate->toDateString(),
        'end_date' => $startDate->addDays($i % 4 == 3 ? 6 : 7)->toDateString(),
    ];
}

dd($data);
```

We use here `%` to loop over seasons, and for all cases we add 7 days except when there is Autumn (then we add 6 days to get 27 days in total instead of 28).

As a result you will get:

```
array:100 [▼
  0 => array:3 [▼
    "title" => "Winter"
    "start_date" => "2018-09-20"
    "end_date" => "2018-09-27"
  ]
  1 => array:3 [▼
    "title" => "Spring"
    "start_date" => "2018-09-27"
    "end_date" => "2018-10-04"
  ]
  2 => array:3 [▼
    "title" => "Summer"
    "start_date" => "2018-10-04"
    "end_date" => "2018-10-11"
  ]
  3 => array:3 [▼
    "title" => "Autumn"
    "start_date" => "2018-10-11"
    "end_date" => "2018-10-17"
  ]
  4 => array:3 [▼
    "title" => "Winter"
    "start_date" => "2018-10-17"
    "end_date" => "2018-10-24"
  ]
  5 => array:3 [▼
    "title" => "Spring"
    "start_date" => "2018-10-24"
    "end_date" => "2018-10-31"
  ]
  6 => array:3 [▼
    "title" => "Summer"
    "start_date" => "2018-10-31"
    "end_date" => "2018-11-07"
  ]
  7 => array:3 [▼
    "title" => "Autumn"
    "start_date" => "2018-11-07"
    "end_date" => "2018-11-13"
  ]
  8 => array:3 [▼
    "title" => "Winter"
    "start_date" => "2018-11-13"
    "end_date" => "2018-11-20"
  ]
  9 => array:3 [▶]
  10 => array:3 [▶]
  ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [strtotime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) and [date](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) functions, with some basic loop control structures.

Check the following (**[Rextester Demo](http://rextester.com/CVU45656)**):

```
$counter = 0; // counter to manage loops
$max_counter = 100; // maximum number of entries required

$data = array(); //initialize return array

// seasons with their corresponding days
$seasons = array('Winter' => 7, 
                 'Spring' => 7, 
                 'Summer' => 7, 
                 'Autumn' => 6);

// Initializing first date for the loop begin
$start_date = date('Y-m-d');

while( $counter < $max_counter) {

    foreach ($seasons as $season => $daygap) {

        // determining end date
        $end_date = strtotime("+" . $daygap . " day", strtotime($start_date));
        $end_date = date('Y-m-d', $end_date);

        $data[] = array(
                        'title'      => $season, 
                        'start_date' => $start_date, 
                        'end_date'   => $end_date
                       );

        // setting end_date to start_date for next season
        $start_date = $end_date;

        // increment counter
        $counter++;
    }
}

// check the array
var_dump($data);
```